# PHP Laravel 5.2 belongs to

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 3 tables Users, Profiles, and Friends.

Users contains users, obviously.
Then I got the Profiles and Friends table (see below).

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('profiles', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->string('picture')->nullable();
        $table->string('status')->nullable();
        $table->string('text')->nullable();
        $table->boolean('show_sex');
        $table->boolean('show_dob');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id_sender')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('user_id_receiver')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id_sender')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('user_id_receiver')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->integer('status'); // 1 = friends, 2 = under validation
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

As you can see, i created some foreign keys that relates to the Users table.

The Friends table contains all friendships between users (the status field will determine if the friendship is under validation or validated).
I have the default User model that comes with Laravel 5.2 and was wondering, how can I easely get all the friendships, that belongs to the signed user?
Could I use something like `belongsTo()` or something to easely get all friendrequests where the user_id_receiver field is the same as the signed users id? I didn't quiet understand the documentation for hasOne or belongsTo.. Would be nice if someone could clearify how it actually works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My best suggest is before you go directly to coding and ask about Laravel, try to design your database table (ER-design) when you know that it will make you code logic easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should use One-to-one relation between `User` and `Profile` models and One-to-many relation between `User` and `Friend` models. Add this to both models - `Friend` and `Profile`:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('app\User');
}
```

And add this to `User` model:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('app\Profile');
}

public function friend()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\Friend');
}
```

And then you could use Eloquent to get data:

```
$signedUserId = Auth::user()->id;
$currentUserFriendRequests = Friend::where('user_id_receiver', $signedUserId)->get();
```

I hope this will be helpful.

Comment: Well, that actually made sense to me. And, it seems like it's working with that solution. Thanks!